# How to get defined Tax rate percent prgramatically?

Tags: magento, tax, sales-tax

We have created tax rates in `sales->Taxes->Zone&Rates` with Rate Percent of xx.xx, Can we fetch this fetch this details programmatically before placing order for using it API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for this question,

```
$customer_tax_class = '5';
        $rates = $tax->load($customer_tax_class, 'customer_tax_class_id');
        $request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest()->setProductClassId(2)->setCustomerClassId(5);
        echo $percent = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($request);
```